# Am I right about this copy constructor, or they are lying to me?

Tags: c++

Say you got a class Student:

```
class Student{

  char *_name;

  Student(char *name){
  _name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
  strcpy(_name, name);
 }

 void setName(char *name){
  _name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
  strcpy(_name, name);
 }

 char* getName(){return _name;}
}
```

Now, it is just a basic class. 
   When I do this :

```
Student s("Mike");
   Student s1 = s; // calls default copy constructor
   s1.setName("Bruce");

   cout << s.getName();
   cout << s1.getName();
```

Shouldn't they now both be called Bruce because copy constructor is copying address to the source char and both pointers point to the same thing?

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: Also you have a memory leak in `setName`

Comment: Because am trying yo gain deeper knowledge in pointers.

Comment: when I add delete[] _name in setName it produces the expected behaviour

Comment: Should `name = new char[strlen(name)+1];` be `_name = new char[strlen(name)+1];`

Comment: yes, that was a typo

Comment: Also look up the `const` keyword - could use this in multiple places in your code to make it more robust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, after the copy, both objects' `_name` pointers point to the same string in memory.  But when you call `setName`, it allocates a *new* string, with different contents, and sets `s1`'s `_name` to point to that instead.  So in the end, the two objects refer to different strings.

Comment: Thank you, this was the thing I was missing.

Comment: Also, as others have mentioned, this code leaks memory since it doesn't call `delete[]` on the arrays it allocates.  You mentioned that you're trying to learn about pointers, and freeing memory when you're done with it is an important part of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you are looking for:

```
class Student{
private:
  char *_name;
public:
  Student(const char *const name) : _name(nullptr) {
      setName(name);
 }
~Student() { delete[] _name; }
 void setName(const char *const name) {
  delete[] _name;
  _name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
  strcpy(_name, name);
 }

 const char* getName() const {return _name;}
};
```

As they are two different student objects they can have different names. So in your code `s1` is given the name *bruce* and `s` will have the name *mike* as expected

Answer (score 0):

strcpy function copies the content of char array (that is all characters including the terminating null character with code 0). Both would be called "Bruce" if you had _name = name in your copying constructor.

Comment: but what if name is bigger that _name?

Comment: Actually it should be:
`delete [] _name;
 _name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
  strcpy(_name, name);`

I think you missed the '_' when you created new array.

Comment: yes, with this code in setName() both are called 'Bruce'. Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: If by "this code" you mean `_name = name` you copy the address of the char array passed as a parameter. In this case both s._name and s1._name are pointers to the same place in memory.